# Solve for x: $\sin^{-1}(\sin (\frac{2x^2+4}{x^2+1}))<\pi -3$

Tags: inverse-function

Solve for x:
$\sin^{-1}(\sin(\frac{2x^2+4}{x^2+1}))<\pi -3$

My approach : $\pi -3$ is approximately equal to $\frac{\pi}{22.42}$ and $\frac{2x^2+4}{x^2+1}$ is positive as no condition is imposed on x we can take any value but i am not able to proceed

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
You know $\sin^{-1}(\sin u)=u$ then solve
$$\sin^{-1}(\sin(\frac{2x^2+4}{x^2+1}))=\frac{2x^2+4}{x^2+1}=2+\frac{2}{x^2+1}<\pi -3$$

Comment: It's only true that $\sin^{-1}(\sin(u)) = u$ if $u$ is between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$, though.

Comment: yes, of course. $\pi-3<\pi/2$.